# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android development and I want first to get the `Hello World` application running.
I am using Eclipse IDE and the Android 4.0.3 version 15 SDK. I copied everything from a tutorial site, but when I try to run the application on the `virtual device` I get this error:

```
[2012-02-01 11:31:23 - Android_test] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
[2012-02-01 11:31:23 - Android_test] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-02-01 11:31:23 - Android_test] Launch canceled!
```

Here is my class in the `com.maze.app` package:
    package com.maze.app;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity{
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);

    }

}
```

and the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.maze.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="@string/app_name"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="HelloAndroid" android:launchMode="standard" android:enabled="true"></activity>
</application>
```

Here is the configuration of the `Virtual Device`:

```
Name: AndroidVD
CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi-v7a)
Path: path\to\avd
Target: Android 4.0.3(API level 15)
Skin: WVGA800
hw.lcd.density: 240
hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8
vm.heapSize: 48
hw.ramSize:512
```

What is the problem?

EDIT:
The application is not running on the Virtual Device:
Here is what I get on LogCat(some of the lines):

```
D/PackageManager(92): New package installed in /data/app/com.maze.app-2.apk
D/dalvikvm(92): GC_CONCURRENT freed 660K, 9% free 11935K/12999K, paused 18ms+72ms
I/ActivityManager(92): Force stopping package com.maze.app uid=10040
D/BackupManagerService(92): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.maze.app flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
V/BackupManagerService(92): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.maze.app
```

Comment: in your manifiest file, `android:targetSdkVersion="@string/app_name"` is mentioned. is it a typo?

Comment: @Karthik No, it's not a typo. That is what the wizard generated.

Comment: This may also be up use for someone [this worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24438395/754485)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

It is due to `android:targetSdkVersion="@string/app_name"` in your manifiest file.
Change it to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

The `targetSdkVersion` should be an integer, but `@string/app_name` would be a string. I think this causing the error.

**EDIT:**
You have to add a default `intent-filter` in your `manifiest` file for the activity. Then only android can launch the activity. otherwise you will get the below error in your console window.

```
[2012-02-02 09:17:39 - Test] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-02-02 09:17:39 - Test] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Add the following to your `<activity>` tag.

```
<activity android:name="HelloAndroid" android:launchMode="standard" android:enabled="true">  
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't get the error anymore. But The Virtual Device starts and it doesn't show me `Hello Android`. Do I have to start it somehow? If yes, how? If not, why isn't it working?

Comment: if you run from eclipse, the app will be automatically started after installation. So the activity should show up on the AVD screen. When the AVD starts, it would be in Locked state (screen lock), once you unlock the screen you can see the `Hello Android` text.

Comment: Yes, it starts in Lock state, but when I unlock it, it just shows me the wallpaper and some icons at the bottom. There is no `Hello Android`.

Comment: any errors on the Logcat? you can add some [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) statements in onCreate() and see if they are shown in the Logcat window.

Comment: If by `Logcat` you mean the `Console` in Eclipse, then the answer is no. I don't get any errors. If that's not what you meant by Logcat, please tell me where I can find it.

Comment: It is not console. Logcat is a window where we can view log messages. In Eclipse, open `Window->Show View->Others`, under `Android`, you will see `LogCat`. click it, it will open a window.

Comment: I edited the question and added some lines from LogCat. What do they mean?

Comment: Thank you! It works. It starts very very slow, but it works. Is it normal to be so slow(5 min)?

Comment: you are welcome. yea, AVD is very slow. It depends on the PC configuration also.

Comment: @Karthik I set neither minSdk nor targetSdk. But I get this error during install APK. I even decompiled final APK, and there is no min/target attribute.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Could you give me some more details, like what is the exact error, steps you are following, dev environment (Android studio?).

Comment: @Karthik I'm working on AOSP, with gcc 4.2 I think, and JDK 1.6. What information you need more?

Answer (score 30):

This means the version of android of your avd is older than the version being used to compile the code

Comment: You build AVD's (Android Virtual Devices) given a certain set of features (Screen size, code version, camera status).  Build one that is the same as your target API version.  Also build an older one for compatibility testing.

Answer (score 18):

This error occurs when the sdk-version installed on your device (real or virtual device) is smaller than `android:minSdkVersion` in your android manifest.

You either have to decrease your `android:minSdkVersion` or you have to specify a higher api-version for your AVD.

Keep in mind, that it is not always trivial to decrease `android:minSdkVersion` as you have to make sure, your app cares about the actual installed API and uses the correct methods:

```
AsyncTask<String, Object, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Object, String>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (params == null) return "";
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (String p : params) {
             b.append(p);
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
};
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"Hello", " ", "world!");
} else {
    task.execute("Hello", " ", "world!");
}
```

Using the android-support-library and/or libraries like [actionbar-sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) will help you dealing especially with widgets of older versions.

Answer (score 15):

I am using Android Studio 0.8.1. I have a project's gradle file like below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.omersonmez.widgets.hotspot"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

My emulator was android 4.0. 
So i modified my emulator and made api level 4.0.3(apilevel 15).
It worked.

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the responses described here but my solution was changing inside my `build.gradle` file `minSdkVersion` from 8 to 9 because some libraries in my project can´t work with API 8, that´s was the reason for the message `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.tuna.hello.androidstudioapplication"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
...
...
...
```

Comment: This sounds like it translates to some included library's min SDK is 9.

Answer (score 2):

You will see the same error if you are trying to install an apk that was built using

```
compileSdkVersion "android-L"
```

Even for devices running the final version of Android 5.0.
Simply change this to

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fix for new Android 6.0 Marshmallow**
Fixed my issue when I updated to API 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) by updating the build tools version to 23.0.0 as follows:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
...
```

And went to **File > Project Structure** , chose **Properties** tab then updated the **Compile Sdk version** to "API 23: Android 5.X (MNC)" and the **Build tools version** to "23.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

In my case I edited a project having this in the AndroidManifest.xml file, and which was ginving me the above error, at runtime:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

What I did just, was to change minSdkVersion="17", to minSdkVersion="16". My resulting tag was:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Now I'm not getting the error anymore..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Received the same error , the problem was difference in the version of Android SDK which AVD was using and the version in AndroidManifest file. I could solve it by correcting the

**android:minSdkVersion="16"**

to match with AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Android Studio. I got this error when min/targetSDKVersion were set to 17. While looking thro this thread, I tried to change the minSDKVersion, voila..problem fixed. Go figure.. :(

```
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your build.gradle and that it doesn't use a newer SDK version than what is installed on your AVD. That's only if you use Android Studio though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally new like me, you must install the minimum SDK at first. Check the link.

This worked out perfectly for me:

[Same problem other post with a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24616329/2903068)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the run configurations `module` drop-down list from `wearable` to `android.`  (This error happened to me when I tried running Google's I/O Sched open-source app.) It would automatically pop up the configurations every time I tried to run until I changed the `module` to `android`.

You can access the configurations by going to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` -> `General` tab -> `Module: [drop-down-list-here]`

Answer (score 0):

I found that making the recommended change in the manifest didn't solve my problem.

The fix was found in the GradleScripts folder, in the build.gradle file for the Module:app.

Inside this file (build.gradle) the following line was modified.
minSdkVersion 22
I changed this '22' value to '19' for my particular phone and the build completed without error.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, my advice is to change virtual device. Download "Genimotion" application, its easy to use and there are a lot of any devices you need

Answer (score 0):

Go in your project's `build.cradle` file and add

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
```

}`

This makes it that your application conforms to the minimum SDK your device is running.

Answer (score 0):

In our case using Flutter, some of our plugins required minimum API level 23  (Android 6.1) due to which several old devices could not install our app . For example, a Huawei Android 5.1 device could not install the app as the Flutter project's several plugins demanded minimum API 23 or Android version 6.1 .

To make a solution in such a case:

1. Either, remove those plugins to make your app compatible with old phones
2. Or, keep using high-API-required Flutter plugins that may lose old-device users .

[image: Installed_Failed_Older_SDK]

Answer (score -1):

Ionic Android emulator error **INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK**

So, basically it means that the installation has failed due to having an older SDK version than the targetSdkVersion specified in your app (it's a Gradle issue).
Just edit the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following code:

```html
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

After days looking for the solution, that's it.

Works fine for me!

Answer (score -1):

If the error "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK" appears, you must change the version of minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest to the one specified in the android emulator: see Settings -> About phone -> Android version.

Comment: Hi @cupoma58, welcome. How is this different that the other answers?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I've changed my `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` to `18` from `21`:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

Now I can install my app successfully.