# What does "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]" mean in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo

I got this **Froyo** (2.2) device that I am using to make an app.
When I try to run the app directly to the device it shows an error saying

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.HelloWorldProject
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

and in another window there's an error saying

```
Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly
```

What seem to make the said errors?

EDIT:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.test.helloworld"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:debuggable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        <activity
                android:name="com.example.HelloWorldProject.MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the minimum sdk that your app will run with? Perhaps your app is being created for a version that's higher than your device.

Comment: I am using api level **8**

Comment: Could you please post your manifest?

Comment: I already edited the question to be able to present the manifest file

Answer (score 33):

After I changed

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bocheng.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 'L' #change this to 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

in `build.gradle` file.

it works

Comment: This is really the correct answer. The targetSdkVersion should not be using 'L' for devices. The OP should accept this as the correct answer. Found some many answers that failed to address this issue.

Comment: @QinZhengquan where is this defaultConfing I don't see it in AndroidManifest.xml, where can I find this?

Comment: @iqueqiorio in `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 30):

This error

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Means that you're trying to install an app that has a higher `minSdkVersion` specified in its manifest than the device's API level. Change that number to `8` and it should work. I'm not sure about the other error, but it may be related to this one.

Comment: Yes, I am already using API level **8** while having the error.

Comment: I tried to do a hello world with 3 and still couldn't get it running.

Comment: I set neither minSdk nor targetSdk. But I get this error during install APK. I even decompiled final APK, and there is no min/target attribute.

Answer (score 10):

Besides checking the right `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`, make sure you have installed all necessary `tools` and correct `SDK Platform` for your preferred Android Version in `SDK Manager`. In *Android Studio* klick on ***Tools*** -> ***Android*** -> ***SDK Manager***. Then install at minimum (for Android 2.2 without emulator):

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools (latest)
- Android 2.2 (API 8)

  - SDK Platform
  - Google APIs

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't have a `minSdkVersion` set in your `build.gradle` with a value higher than 8. If you don't specify it at all, it's supposed to use the value in your `AndroidManfiest.xml`, which seems to already be properly set.

Comment: where can i see build.gradle file in my project

Comment: I set neither minSdk nor targetSdk. But I get this error during install APK. I even decompiled final APK, and there is no min/target attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Just removing `uses-sdk` tag works for me for such problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]** basically means that the installation has failed due to the target location (AVD/Device) having an older SDK version than the targetSdkVersion specified in your app.

**N/B Froyo 2.2 API 8**

To fix this simply change

**targetSdkVersion="17"** to **targetSdkVersion="8"**

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure the Select Run/Debug Configuration is wear or mobile as per your installation in android studio...

Answer (score 1):

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]**

For **Sumsung note3** I just edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add the following code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file `package` attribute is set to `com.test.helloworld` however your activity class is under different package. Change your MyActivity class package to `com.example.helloworld`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.The device system version is older then the sdk minSdkVersion。
 I just modified the minSdkVersion from android_L to 19
 to target my nexus 4.4.4.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    **compileSdkVersion 'android-L'** modified to 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.antwei.uiframework.ui"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'** modified to compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

how to modified the value by ide.
select file->Project Structure -> Facets -> android-gradle and then modified the compile Sdk Version from android_L to 19

sorry I don't have enough reputation to add pictures

Answer (score 0):

This is because you mobile has older sdk version than your application..!!!
It means your application need sdk version suppose Lollipop but you mobile has version kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your gradle file the following way

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "package.com.app"
    minSdkVersion 8 //this should be lower than your device
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In android studio: reduce minSDKversion. It will work...

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "healthcare.acceliant.trianz.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go to File>Project Structure > Modules and Change your Source Compability to a lower version before Ive done this, Ive changed in build.gradle
mindSdk and tragetSdk from 31 to 30.
Now I can use the Emulator without problems

Answer (score 0):

Go to /Gradle Scripts/build.gradle.kts and change those infos to the desired ones:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.mya"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.mya"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

Change file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```