# Android Studio Install failed older sdk

Tags: android, sdk

im using Android Studio since a few days!
I want to use my phone(nexus 5 android version:4.4.3) as app-tester and debugger.
I've set my phone in target Device. There aren't usb-driver problem. The device is recognized by PC. Ok!Now i've this problem:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-04e2b217251fce16
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\chaw359\AndroidStudioProjects\UGHO\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.chaw359.ugho
Installing com.example.chaw359.ugho
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.chaw359.ugho"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.chaw359.ugho
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

My app is a simple "Hello World", nothing problem with code! I want to understand why the installation fails!

Comment: what all values have you given in uses_sdk in Manifest file?

Comment: How about checking existing question? [Android Studio : Failure INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk) and [What does “Failure INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK” mean in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622255/what-does-failure-install-failed-older-sdk-mean-in-android-studio)

Comment: I resolved updating sdk... sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You can modified your `build.gradle`

According to me:

modified the minSdkVersion low.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication1"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

-Go to built.gradle(module:app) inside gradle scripts

-Check the SDK or API version of the virtual device or the real device that you
are using

-set the the minSdkVersion to be less than or equal to that of your devices API/SDK version