# Failure INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK -error

Tags: android, android-activity

Trying to run an app on my samsung tablet using android studio and i keep getting this message

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

what does this mean and how do i solve this problem ?

Comment: Google `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622255/what-does-failure-install-failed-older-sdk-mean-in-android-studio

Comment: There are a variety of reasons and workarounds that I found when I Googled.

Comment: @DSlomer64 i changed the minsdkversion , but now get an error saying unfortunately app is not working, please try again ?

Comment: Same error or what? BTW, I  have a meeting to attend shortly so I may not get back to this soon. Not sure i can actually help anyway. Did you follow Google links?

Comment: i am running an the app on my samsung tablet it comes up on the device .when i click on the app it goes to a blank screen , then shows the message unfortunately app is not working i have cleared the cache  ?

Comment: @DSlomer64 - app unable to run on the device

Comment: Are there error messages, especially exceptions, that tell you where the error occurred? If the message is `Unfortunately ... has stopped ...`, there surely are messages to refer to. You should Google `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK` and follow those links. It seems to be a common error with no single cause, although the message means that you've sent an app compiled such that the device can't handle it since its SDK is older. What version are you compiling to? What Android version does the device have?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622255/what-does-failure-install-failed-older-sdk-mean-in-android-studio) is a good link to start with if you're getting the INSTALL_FAILED... error