# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK when running Sample CardView Example

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I imported the `CardView` Sample app using Android Studio with `Import Sample` option from GitHub. No issues.

However, When I tried to run this sample app on my Android device running `Android 4.2`, I am getting error as per below screenshot:

[image]

I Google the issue and found this link: [Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093709/installation-error-install-failed-older-sdk)

As per the answers in that link, I need to make targetSdkVersion to match my device OS version So, I tried to change the `targetSdkVersion` as below (Android 4.2 = API Level 17)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
 android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

But even after this change I am unable to run this app on my android device.

Any hint on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you installing app on "real" device or AVD?

Comment: its device (Samsung Galaxy device running on Android 4.2)!

Comment: Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Please read the question once, I mentioned all these details. Its Android Studio!

Comment: I read the question, I ask because you are mixing eclipse code on Android Studio, to change `targetSdkVersion` on Android Studio You need change on `build.gradle`file, do not use `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
 android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` on `AndroidManifest.xml`.

 To implement `CardView` on Android Studio you only need add that code on `Build.gradle` file: `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'` and compile again your app, but first Unistall your app on your device and try again.

Comment: If you need help to change `Build.Gradle` file, tell me and I will post an answer

Comment: @Aspicas It is fixed! All i need was do clean build and run the app once again! Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Update these lines in your build.gradle to stick with the latest stable release (Android 4.2, API 17):

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.daroath.actionbar"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is fixed! All i need was do clean build and run the app once again! Thanks for your input though!