# How to set up environment for mobile automation testing (both Android and IOS) using Ruby, Appium and Rspec

Tags: android, ruby, testing, rspec, appium

Currently I am trying to perform the the most common things to start mobile automation testing (android and IOS). I've installed appium, android sdk, etc. (everything that is needed).
I've written the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/core'
require 'touch_action'
require 'appium_lib'

describe "Mobile Web Gestures" do
  before(:all) do
    desired_caps = {
        caps: {
            platformName: 'Android',
            versionNumber: '4.3',
            deviceName: 'Sergey Kay (GT-I9300)',
            device: 'Android',
            app: '../app-mockBLE_SK.apk'
            # browserName: 'Chrome'
        }
    }
    @driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps).start_driver
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 120
  end

  it "performs mobile" do
    sleep 60
  end
end
```

But this code doesn't install and run the application. I see "**A new session could not be created. (Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/beb26e401b5b156e51450a453b9cd84a.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK])","origValue":"Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/beb26e401b5b156e51450a453b9cd84a.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]**" error in Apium.
What can be wrong and what I've missed?
Any suggestions how to improve this are welcome!

Comment: Please add full error. Also double check capabilities, could be simple mismatch there.

Comment: Added full error text.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093709/installation-error-install-failed-older-sdk

Comment: This issue is for Java((( I use Ruby.

Comment: Yep, but the issue is coming from App itself, not from your tests. You need newer Android version to run that application.

Comment: That is it!! I've tried on Android 6.0.1 and app started correctly!

Comment: Cool! I'd recommend google your error first next time :)